# netfilter-persistent starts on boot, but iptables does not

Tags: iptables

I have netfilter-persistent and iptables-persistent installed.
Netfilter-persistent starts after a reboot.
I have rules saved at `/etc/iptables/rules.v4`
Iptables does not start.
`sudo systemctl restart netfilter-persistent` does not change iptables status

[image]

[image: netfilter-persistent/plugins.d/15-ip5tables]

Comment: `iptables` isn't a 'service' that runs, it's integrated into the kernel and netfilter components, loaded at boot time.  How have you tested that iptables is 'not running'?  Does `sudo iptables -L -n -v` show your rules after boot?